# Touchpad "Tap to Click" option not working

Tags: 18.04, drivers, touchpad, synaptics, xorg.conf

I am facing a very strange problem in Ubuntu 18.04 after an update. I am unable to select the "Tap to Click" option from the settings. When I open settings from the GUI, every time I see it OFF, when I enable it, my touchpad "Tap to Click" doesn't work and after closing it, the setting again defaults to OFF. I have tried using `dconf-editor` to set it and preferences also get saved but touchpad "Tap to Click" still doesn't work.

Here is the output of `xinput`:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PixArt Dell MS116 USB Optical Mouse       id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN1200:00 04F3:3090 Touchpad            id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus Wireless Radio Control               id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD           id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Here is the output of my touchpad properties using `xinput list-props <id>`:

```
Device 'ELAN1200:00 04F3:3090 Touchpad':
    Device Enabled (197):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (199): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Tapping Enabled (349): 0
    libinput Tapping Enabled Default (350): 0
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (351):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (352):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (353):   0
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (354):   0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (355):  1, 0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (356):  1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (331):   1
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (332):   0
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (357):    1
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (358):    1
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (333):    1, 1, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (334):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (335):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Click Methods Available (359): 1, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled (360):    0, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled Default (361):    1, 0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (338):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (339):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (340): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (341): 0.000000
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (345): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (346): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (316): 1, 1
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (317):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (318):    0, 0
    Device Node (319):  "/dev/input/event10"
    Device Product ID (320):    1267, 12432
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (347):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (348):   1
```

Here is the output of `xinput list-props <id>` after adding `Option "Tapping" "True"`:

```
Device 'ELAN1200:00 04F3:3090 Touchpad':
    Device Enabled (197):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (199): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Tapping Enabled (349): 0
    libinput Tapping Enabled Default (350): 0
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (351):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (352):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (353):   0
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (354):   0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (355):  1, 0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (356):  1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (331):   1
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (332):   0
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (357):    1
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (358):    1
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (333):    1, 1, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (334):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (335):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Click Methods Available (359): 1, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled (360):    0, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled Default (361):    1, 0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (338):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (339):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (340): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (341): 0.000000
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (345): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (346): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (316): 1, 1
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (317):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (318):    0, 0
    Device Node (319):  "/dev/input/event8"
    Device Product ID (320):    1267, 12432
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (347):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (348):   1
```

Here is the output of `cat /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf`:

```
# Match on all types of devices but joysticks
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput pointer catchall"
        MatchIsPointer "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput keyboard catchall"
        MatchIsKeyboard "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
        Option "Tapping" "True"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput touchscreen catchall"
        MatchIsTouchscreen "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput tablet catchall"
        MatchIsTablet "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection
```

It would be a great help if someone can help with a fix to this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command.

Comment: Now please add output of `xinput list-props 14`

Comment: It is now clear enough. I need another output: `apt policy xserver-xorg`.

Comment: Now it is 100% clear. Hold on. I am updating the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your device is managed by `xorg-synaptics` for some reason, while default in Ubuntu 18.04 should be `libinput`.

Run in a terminal

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-libinput
sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

and reboot.

Run `sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf`

and add `Option "Tapping" "True"` there to the touchpad section like this:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
        Option "Tapping" "True"
EndSection
```

Save the file by Crtl+O and exit by Ctrl+X. Reboot and it should start working.

Comment: It did not work for me. I tried the commands, but it still shows me the same `dmesg` and I am unable to set "Tap to Click".

Comment: The log is not that important. What does `xinput list-props 14` show now?

Comment: updated the `xinput list-props 14` output.

Comment: Hi! I appreciate your help and quick response but it's still the same situation. I added the line and it looks exactly the same as you mentioned but tapping is still not working. When I am enabling it from the `gnome-control-center` or `dconf-editor`, it still goes back to OFF after closing it.

Comment: Then it may be a kernel issue. Insall HWE kernel by `sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-18.04`.

Comment: If that doesn't help either, it can be a hardware problem too.

Comment: And check is Tapping is enabled now in `xinput list-ptops 14`.

Comment: Updated, I don't see any change in `libinput Tapping Enabled (349): 0`. Plus, I don't think it should be a hardware issue as it as working earlier.

Comment: If tapping is not enabled, then you did something wrong. Run `xinput set-prop 14 349 1` ans see if tapping starts working.

Comment: Ah, `xinput set-prop 14 349 1` worked. But the change goes off after restarting. I think adding this as a script to `/etc/init.d/` should be a temporary solution?

Comment: `/etc/init.d/` is a wrong place. It won't work. Maybe you made some typo in `40-libinput.conf`. Please add `cat /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf` to your question.

Comment: updated the output of `cat /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf`

Comment: Try to add it to the first section too. Maybe it is some glitch that the device is not detected as a touchpad. All add to all sections. It is wierd that tapping is not enabled by default.

Comment: I added `Option "Tapping" "True"` to all the sections, it didn't work out. Is there any way to find out why the change is not being implemented or what could have change after the system update which led to this problem?.

Comment: You can add the `xinput set-prop 14 349 1` to automatically started applications. But it is weird.

Comment: Thank you for all your time and help!